# "Analytic Continuation" of the Convolution Operator?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

The convolution of two functions $f, g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined as:

$$(f \ast g)(t) := \displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(\tau)g(t - \tau)d\tau,$$

and can be generalised to higher dimensions. A result of significant importance is the well-known convolution theorem, a version of which states that:

$$\displaystyle \hat{f} \ast \hat{g} = \widehat{f \cdot g},$$

where $\hat{f}$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$. Since it can also be shown that $\ast$ is associative, then we also have:

$$\hat{f}^{\otimes_{k}} = \underbrace{\hat{f} \ast ... \ast \hat{f}}_{k \text{ terms}} = \widehat{f^k},$$

for any positive integer $k$. Now, as silly as this sounds, I would like to investigate this for $k = 1/2$. That is, given that we know the Fourier coefficients of $f$, can we derive, in terms of convolutions, the Fourier coefficients of $\sqrt{f}$ ?

There is such an extension of the convolution operator, known as fractional convolution, for which several papers have been published, the majority of which fall in the category of signal processing. However, the "fractional convolution theorems" seem to depend on being able to write $f$ as a product of functions whose Fourier coefficients are known (see, for example, David Mustard's 1995 paper entitled Fractional Convolution). But this is not possible here.

Does anyone know of an analytic continuation of $\otimes_{k}$ to rational values of $k$ that would allow this to be possible? Otherwise, are there any other ways to find the Fourier coefficients of $\sqrt{f}$ given that the Fourier coefficients of $f$ are known?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can write:

$$\displaystyle f^{\otimes_{k}} = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{\mathcal{F}(f)^{k+1}\},$$

as an analytic continuation for $k \not \in \mathbb{N},$ where $\mathcal{F}(f)$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$.

Comment: Does $F(f) ^{k} $ mean $F(f^{k}) $ or $(F(f)) ^{k} $ or something else altogether?

Comment: It means $(\mathcal{F}(f))^k$.

Comment: I revisited the David Mustard reference you gave me in the post above this. I have a few questions on your reply (i.e. $F^{-1}((F(f))^k)$) and  also from that reference paper: 1. Did you mean $F^{-1}((F(f))^{1+k})$ ? A full convolution would give $F^{-1}((F(f))^{2})$, so a half convolution should be $F^{-1}((F(f))^{1.5})$ intuitively right? Am I missing something? 2. In that paper, for half convolution, the angle to choose is $\theta = \pi/4$ right?

Comment: Yes -- I've edited the answer accordingly. Yes, that would be the right angle to choose, although there are more recent papers out there which offer more simplified versions of fractional convolution (though not necessarily with the same level of detail that Mustard's paper gives).

Comment: I did not understand which part of mustard's formula takes care of the width of the resulting convolution. For a fixed width signal (say a rectangular pulse of width 1), full convolution with itself should result in a width of 2. A half convolution should spread out out only to 1.5. The integral $Q(z)$ in that paper didn't seem to be scaling $z$ according to $\theta$. Also when I plug in $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$, it results in double integrals , that too an integral of a Fresnel integral no less. Even wolfram-alpha gives up on those integral of fresnel integrals.

Comment: Do you have any other paper suggestions with an explicit formula for fractional convolution?

Answer (score 3):

**Existence** of such a continuation is not a problem. You can simply define $\hat{f}^{\otimes_{k}} = \widehat{f^k}$ for arbitrary positive reals $k$.  Of course you'll want $f^k$ to have a Fourier transform, so you'll want, say, $f \in L^{1/k}$.  And you'll want to specify which branch of the $k$'th power to take when $f$ is not always positive, perhaps the principal branch.

But none of this addresses the problem of actually computing $\widehat{f^k}$ from $\widehat{f}$.

Comment: I have found two suitable analytic continuations: one of which preserves many of the original "nice" properties of the convolution operator (e.g. commutativity), and one of which does not. Is it only necessary for the analytic continuation of the operator to agree with the original operator on all values for which the original operator is defined on, or must the analytic continuation preserve those additional "nice" properties too?

More generally, how does the principle of analytic continuation differ when applied to operators as opposed to analytic functions on the complex plane?

Comment: @user363087 - Do you have any link for these? I am looking for the same thing, basically something like k=3/2.

Comment: @Srini Google "fractional convolution mustard" -- there's a paper in the first link, written by David Mustard in 1995, detailing some formulae for fractional convolutions. You can also check out page 3 of "A sampling theorem for the fractional Fourier transform
without band-limiting constraints" -- I don't have a direct link at the moment, but googling it should take you to somewhere where you can download it. In the references of that paper you should be able to find various other related papers in that area.

Comment: @user363087, thanks.  I will check these out.